# Linux PostgreSQL 9.4 to Windows PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql, linux, migration, windows

I had to switch from PostgreSQL 9.4 on Linux to PostgreSQL 13 on Windows

Normal restore was not successful.

Can somebody share experience with such case?

**EDIT 1:**

On linux I use:

```
pg_dump -c -O -U postgres mydbname -h localhost -p 5432 --disable-dollar-quoting -i | gzip > /backup/mydbname.gz
```

on windows I use 7zip to unpack gz file and then
the problem is that restoring with

```
psql.exe -U postgres -f c:\Backup\mydbname
```

I get such errors:

```
psql:c:/Backup/mydbname:65: ERROR:  relation "public.sprawy" does not exist
```

or:

```
psql:c:/Backup/mydbname:321: ERROR:  index "adnotacje_id_sprawa_idx" does not exist
```

or:

```
psql:c:/Backup/mydbname:1460: ERROR:  table "uczestnicy" does not exist
```

or:

```
psql:c:/Backup/mydbname:1461: ERROR:  sequence "uczestnicy_seq" does not exist
```

of course the CRM aplication after trying to connect to new server throws errors because restoring was not well, thus we still stay on old installation.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the complete `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` commands you used include the complete and exact error message. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I can absolutely share my experience: using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` works just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just edited my question please take a look again.